# C++ pixel level control over graphics

Tags: c++, graphics

I have been looking all over the web for the simplest solution for this, and currently I have come across nothing that seems simple enough for my needs.

I am looking for a way to manipulate a matrix of pixels manually in C++, platform independent.

Does anyone know of a library that is simple to use that will help me obtain this?

Comment: Pixels within an application/window or any pixel on the screen?

Comment: Please note that platform-independent pixel manipulation is next to impossible for graphics (as opposed to image manipulation), because there's no universally supported pixel format. You'll frequently find you need to special-case the actual processing having chosen your favourite of the formats the platform can display, although many frameworks will guarantee you a format and do software conversion where necessary. So it depends whether you count that as pixel manipulation - you're manipulating some pixels in a buffer, but different values are actually written to the display buffer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/)

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out this library, it looks extremely simple and quite effective!

Answer (score 1):

Use [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)

Answer (score 1):

By virtue of it being platform independent, you're probably not going to find a library that does only this. There are libraries like SDL and directFB that will let you do this, but not without extra baggage. X11 may even be a better choice. It supports things you don't need, but it also allows you to easily render pixels directly to the screen (or window, as the case may be).